# Rails 5: Local variables in form partial

Tags: controller, instance-variables

Why are some instance variables available in the view without the '@' symbol? Is it a convenience provided by Rails where instance variables matching the name of the controller are available or is something else at work here?

Ex:

**picks_controller.rb**

```
@pick = Pick.new
@show = Show.new
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= pick.class %> // no exception raised
<%= show.class %> // "undefined local variable or method `show'" exception raised
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a change in Rails 5. The default view file now passes a local variable to the form partial.

Instead of this...

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

This is the new default...

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form', person: @person %>
```

See this [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13434) for more info.